# Is there any way to get the SQL View parameter list via REST API?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have a view SQL layer with some parameters. I need to use the REST API to guess these parameters and show to the user in the interface to he/she fill the values before submit.

Going to `rest/workspaces/<WS>/datastores/<DS>/featuretypes/` I can see the layer attributes but no info about the view SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a feature type xml representation you should find a virtual table section in the feature type metadadata, that will also contain the sql view declared parameters.

Comment: You're right! Just changed `html` to `xml` in `rest/workspaces/<WS>/datastores/<DS>/featuretypes/myTestView.html` to see many useful data.

Comment: Forgot to say, you can use `.json` too !